# Java: Exception in Application Start Method error

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I'm getting a big trace when trying to run this code which display an image, however I'm not sure why the code isn't running. Any ideas?

```
public class SplashScreen extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        //Parent rootNode = null;

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        gridpane.setHgap(10);
        gridpane.setVgap(10);

        ImageView algLogo = new ImageView();
        Image logo = new Image("D:/Users/Tozu/workspace/ACA 5 OOJP/AlgonquinCollegeLogo.jpg");
        algLogo.setImage(logo);

        final HBox pictureRegion = new HBox();

        pictureRegion.getChildren().add(algLogo);
        gridpane.add(pictureRegion, 1, 1);

        root.getChildren().add(gridpane);

        stage.setTitle("ACA 5");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();       

    }
```

I've also tried a little test class that confirms whether I have the path for the JPG correct and it seems to work fine, so I don't think the problem lies with the JPG path. 
For clarification the JPG is located in the class folder, not in the src folder

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: d
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1121)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at splashPkg.SplashScreen.start(SplashScreen.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1115)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application splashPkg.SplashScreen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the URL file protocol

```
Image logo = new Image("file:D:/Users/Tozu/workspace/ACA 5 OOJP/AlgonquinCollegeLogo.jpg");
                        ^ here
```

From the documentation of Image https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html

```
// load an image and resize it only in one dimension, to the height of 100 and
// the original width, without preserving original aspect ratio
// The image is located in the current working directory
Image image4 = new Image("file:flower.png", 0, 100, false, false);
```

A better way to do the same thing is to use a `File` object (As suggested by [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d))

```
File f = new File("D:/Users/Tozu/workspace/ACA 5 OOJP/AlgonquinCollegeLogo.jpg");
Image logo = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
```

Comment: Don't create the URL yourself: use `new File(...).toURI().toURL()`. In this case, however, it looks like the image is part of the application, so it should be loaded as a resource.

Comment: Indeed. Probably there is an issue with the URL you're using here, since spaces need to be percent encoded in urls...

Comment: Thanks, appreciated!